# Center page where coordinates begins jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm recreating physical map aisles based on their coordinates on a page. I'm creating DIV elements and using css to draw on the page using coordinates x and y.

for example

```
    position: absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:10px;
     left:208;
     top:820;
```

All is good except the  divs start almost half the the screen. So I want to either move the container div close to the top of the page. I tried dividing the coordinates by 4 to get closer to the top of the page but by doing that the map does not look as good.

So what I'm looking for is either way to move the main up or resize the main dive so the aisles start almost the edge of the main Div.

my structure looks like this

```
<div "main">
<div id='cube1" style=position: absolute;width:10px;height:5px;left:250;top:350"></div>
<div id='cube2" style=position: absolute;width:10px;height:5px;left:300;top:450"></div>
and so on....
</div>
```

Comment: we can't see your structure... please edit

Comment: #main must have position:relative. Also specify units for position properties. Also you can specify the top,left,bottom,right properties at once and get rid of dimensions (see here http://alistapart.com/article/conflictingabsolutepositions)

Comment: Thanks. Had to use negative top value.